# How can I set up different shipping options for different countries in Magento ?

Tags: magento

I sell my product internationally. I want to set up different shipping options for different countries. I have setup the FEDEX on my magento already.

How to setup FedEx Int'l Economy or FedEx Int'l Priority based on country/location in Magento?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-fedex-shipping-in-magento/

Comment: I have setup the fedex on my magento already, i want to setup FEDEX options like FedEx Int'l Economy or FedEx Int'l Priority based on country/location.

Comment: @user863541: You haven't posted any code. Is this a programming related question or are you searching for configuration options?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest I recently found is: Go to Promotions>Shopping Cart Price Rules - Here you can setup conditions and your countries and what you want to offer them eg. free shipping. It works well.